# How to read only some column families from Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: python, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Cloud Bigtable table with two column families: `small` and `large`. I'd like to scan all rows and access the value in the `small` column:

```py
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=False)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
table = instance.table(table_id)

for row in table.yield_rows():
    key = row.row_key.decode('utf-8')
    small_value = row.cells[small_cf][b''][0].value
    print(key, small_value)
```

This works, but will also fetch the value of the `large` CF which I don't care about. How do I only fetch the data from a particular set of CFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`FamilyNameRegexFilter`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.FamilyNameRegexFilter) for this, e.g.:

```py
for row in table.yield_rows(filter_=FamilyNameRegexFilter('small')):
```